# Codeigniter3 framework does not send HTML template in mail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Please, do not mark this question as "similar" because I have tried everything. I have a registration where the user gets verification message to his mail. However, I receive mail like this

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
private $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',           
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://mail.wtf.az',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'no-reply@wtf.az',
        'smtp_pass' => 'mypasss',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'utf-8',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

function sendEmail($to_email)
    {
        $from_email = 'no-reply@wtf.az'; //change this to yours
        $subject = 'Verify Your Email Address';
        $data['link'] = 'https://wtf.az/test/user/verify/<?= md5($to_email); ?>';

        $message = $this->load->view('registration/mailing', $data, true);

        //send mail
        $this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
        $this->email->from($from_email, 'WTF');
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $result = $this->email->send();
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences-in-a-config-file - a private config array is pretty much useless ... set it in your config/email.php  and this config will be loaded.

Comment: @sintakonte is it a good idea? Because I have another mail parameters in other pages

Answer (score 0):

please try $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

```
function sendEmail($to_email)
{
    $from_email = 'no-reply@wtf.az'; //change this to yours
    $subject = 'Verify Your Email Address';
    $data['link'] = 'https://wtf.az/test/user/verify/<?= md5($to_email); ?>';

    $message = $this->load->view('registration/mailing', $data, true);

    //send mail
    $this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
    $this->email->from($from_email, 'WTF');
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $result = $this->email->send();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: When I add this, confirmation mail does not come to  mail